# Rspec Mysql2::Error: SAVEPOINT active_record_1 does not exist: ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I have upgraded my ruby on rails application from rails 3 to rails 5.2.8 version. in my test case i am trying to save value of 1 megabyte in column. see below test case.

```
     context "validates value" do
       it "validation size upto 2 megabytes" do
         @template_schedule_data.value = "A" * 1.megabyte
         expect(@template_schedule_data.save).to eq(true)
       end
     end
```

This test case is passing in rails 3 version but in rails 5.2.8 version it is passing sometimes and sometimes failing with below error.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
  Mysql2::Error: SAVEPOINT active_record_1 does not exist: ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.5.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:151:in `_query'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.5.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:151:in `block in query'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.5.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:150:in `handle_interrupt'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.5.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:150:in `query'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/ar-octopus-0.10.2/lib/octopus/abstract_adapter.rb:13:in `instrument'
```

Any idea why this is happening? if i try to assign small value like three or 4 characters then this error is not coming.

Comment: look in log/test.log and compare the scenarios that pass and fail. There should be some clues there. Is the savepoint being created, in both cases? The savepoint might be an artifact of database cleaner (if you're using that). If so, temporarily disable it to see if it has any effect.

Comment: What's the use case for this test? From your test language, you're just testing that MySQL can hold 1mb worth of data, I'd argue that's not a meaningful test of your own code. You should be able to trust that MySQL can do what it says it can do.

Comment: @Chiperific you're saying just trust that the test will pass, and don't bother running it... but it's failing! Doesn't that warrant investigation? One very good reason is to confirm that what you think should occur actually occurs!

Comment: @LesNightingill, that's not at all what I'm saying. I do think OP should find out why the test is failing as it probably points to some other error in their code. I don't think the error is with MySQL and that was my point. I think the test they write should validate that their own code works as expected, not test whether MySQL is being honest about their specs.